# In a REST API client, do you need multiple GET methods for every endpoint?

Tags: rest, api

I have been trying to learn a bit about api clients.
You have an api at www.expamle.com/api and you need to be able to GET all users at www.expamle.com/api/users and also get them by id at www.example.com/api/users/{id} .

In your code do you need to have a separate function to get ALL records and only one record?
What I don't get is how to properly serialize the results since when you get multiple records it returns you an array but it doesn't work with a single record.

Also, would you need more GET functions for other endpoints such as http://www.example.com/api/products/

Comment: That depends on what your code is doing, we can't tell you that. Maybe you only ever need the list. Maybe you only ever need individual resources. Maybe you need both simultaneously, or at different times. So... what's your *question?*

Comment: This is completely unrelated to c# so I have removed that tag. BUT, if you are using ASP.NET you need an `Action` for every endpoint/URL

Comment: The simple clients that are provided on some tutorials usually have one function to get a specific resource like www.example.com/api/users/{id} but don't provide any example if the same function can OR should cover the request for ALL records on that url.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: The C# tag was the reason why I found this question. This is a coding question so the language tag is helpful - and my answer is written in the language Spongie was asking for. I suggest to add back the tag for others to be able to help.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst The question is completely language-agnostic. The OP could be using ASP.NET or PHP and the question would be the same. The language tag is for a language-specific issue, and the OP didn't care to mention what they are using

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto. Confused. The OP tagged to make clear which language is used and text like "how to properly serialize the results" leads to show some code or samples. Just my five cents. ;-)

Comment: @QualityCatalyst You would then need to guess whether he's using Web Services, WCF, ASP.NET Web API, ASP.NET Core or whatever. It's not our job to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,you typically implement the two separate calls with two methods like this (C#):

```
[Route("users")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    // users resource: /api/users/
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetUsers() { ... }

    // single user resource: /api/users/5
    [Route("{id:long}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetUser(long id) { ... }
}
```

This way you can explicitly define your two different routes. You you will find it also easier to deal with the different requests: less code, simpler to read etc. Avoid code redundancy though.

The serialization depends on what you require. There are multiple options. I personally stick to JSON these days. As a human I can read the data easily, yet the package sizes are fairly small compared to SOAP or any custom XML. Dealing with JSON is simple, especially in ASP.NET Core. You just return an `IEnumerable<...>` and the framework takes care of everything else:

```
[Route("")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetUsers()
{
    return Ok(
        new List<Users>
        {
            new User(1, ...),
            new User(2, ...),
            new User(3, ...)
        });
}
```

For other resources, e. g. your products resource, use other controllers. I personally follow the RESTful guidance: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) and [Microsoft Docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx).

Comment: I see. I am using json in asp.net core and it just looked a bit redundant to me to have 2 functions in what in theory could have been done in 1.
For example when I'm trying to get an array of elements from a get request, i can do something like 
`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(jsonString);`
 
but it fails when the get request returns a single element. Seem like it could work if the api wrapped single records in [] or maybe not.

Comment: @Spongie: Any chance to explain what you mean by "it just looked a bit redundant to me"? Here's nothing redundant. On the API consumer side you have two use cases: (1) you require all users and (2) you require just one. What you get back is either or. Regarding the deserialization: here's nothing redundant either. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<User>>(jsonString)` converts the list, `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(jsonString)` a single element. There's nothing redundant. Or what am I missing?

Comment: What I mean is that if the API itself had wrapped their user body response in [], wouldn't it allow for the deserialization to work if you were trying to GET a single record or all of them? Just ignore it if it doenst make much sense.  

A better way to ask my question would be:
If I want to make a REST client where the user can make a GET request on any url he wants, how would the client know which GET function to use, in the simple case of /users/ and /users/{id}

Comment: @Spongie. I see where you're coming from. "If the API itself had wrapped their user body response in []" for a single user, it wouldn't be RESTful anymore ;-)  `[]` means it's a list, not a single resource. If you put `[]` around a single response how is a consumer supposed to understand it's just one resource without counting? When you expect just one user back, putting this into a list is called overhead. Regarding your "better way of asking": I suggest you read more about RESTful approaches. You appear a little confused about its purpose and use cases. Sample links supplied in my answer.